# mysql create trigger syntax error

Tags: mysql

I've check many SO threads ([one of them here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/469784/creating-trigger-for-table-in-mysql-database-syntax-error)) but couldn't find where the issue lies.

I am trying to protect a column from being updated if it's not null, following [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18840796/protect-column-disallow-update-only-allow-insert-if-null-in-mysql).

But I am getting syntax error from mysql. Here's my code:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER lock_x_id
BEFORE UPDATE ON Games
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
  IF (old.xid IS NOT NULL) THEN
    SIGNAL 'error';
  END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: what is the error ?

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''error';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to raise errors via `SIGNAL` you need to specify the `SQLSTATE` which is the error code and for the user defined generic error codes its `45000` along with the message text `MESSAGE_TEXT`

So the trigger becomes as

```
delimiter //
create trigger lock_x_id before update on games
for each row
begin
 if old.xid is not null then
   signal SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Your custom error message';
 end if;
end;//
delimiter ;
```

**Test Case**

```
mysql> select * from games;
+----+------+------+
| id | xid  | val  |
+----+------+------+
|  1 | NULL |    1 |
|  2 | NULL |    2 |
|  3 | NULL |    3 |
|  4 |    1 |    4 |
|  5 |    2 |    5 |
+----+------+------+
```

Lets create the trigger now

```
mysql> delimiter //
mysql> create trigger lock_x_id before update on games
    -> for each row
    -> begin
    ->  if old.xid is not null then
    ->    signal SQLSTATE VALUE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Your custom error message';
    ->  end if;
    -> end;//
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.05 sec)


mysql> update games set xid = 4 where id = 1;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.06 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0

mysql> update games set xid = 5 where id=5;
ERROR 1644 (45000): Your custom error message
```

And after running the above 2 update commands here how the table looks

```
mysql> select * from games;
+----+------+------+
| id | xid  | val  |
+----+------+------+
|  1 |    4 |    1 |
|  2 | NULL |    2 |
|  3 | NULL |    3 |
|  4 |    1 |    4 |
|  5 |    2 |    5 |
+----+------+------+
```

Note that the 2nd update failed and the row is unchanged.

Read more about this https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/signal.html

Comment: works perfect! now the only thing that bugs me is sequelize dosn't let me set `delimiter`. but thanks so much!

Comment: When you use `sequelize` on  node.js , all you need to specify the trigger code and no need to provide `delimiter` the library will take care of that. The delimiter is needed when you run on the CLI. `sequelize.query(/* trigger code*/)` Or you may use hooks to handle the before update event http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/hooks/

Comment: oh man, what can I say?! That's it! I can't thank you enough!